# Is there a way to connect NextJS app on my phone trough local network in development like Create React App does?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

Create-React-App provides a URL that I can connect through my `LAN` network like this:

[image: nextjs terminal output]

Is there a way to expose the NextJS URL through the `LAN` network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server *is* accessible on the local network, as long as the network is configured properly (and doesn't have something like [client isolation](https://medium.com/openwrt-iot/openwrt-how-to-enable-client-isolation-7865d911d295#:%7E:text=Client%20Isolation%20is%20a%20feature%20that%20will%2C%20as,providing%20a%20layer%20of%20security%20to%20your%20network.) enabled). All you need to do is find out which IP address your network's router is allocating to you. On Windows, this can be done by checking the results of `ipconfig`. On Linux, you can use `ip addr`. Then, when you want to access the app from another device, just use the IP found above followed by the port set in next.js.

For example, I have a machine whose network IP address is 192.168.1.2. On that machine, I have a Next app running on port 56381.

> ```
> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:56381, url: http://localhost:56381
> ```

I can access it on my phone by going to `192.168.1.2:56381`.